# how to fix npm error in nodejs for tensor-flow module

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am trying to install  @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4 , but it doens't install. what is the problem ?

```
npm WARN @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@~1.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@~1.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN nodeuploads@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.7.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.7.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/poran/.npm/_logs/2020-04-04T10_31_00_265Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install TF Core and TF Converter before installing TF model

1. `npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-core`
2. `npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-converter`
3. `npm i @tensorflow-models/mobilenet`

Comment: npm WARN @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@~1.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@~1.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I see still same

Comment: npm i tensorflow/tfjs-node

Comment: You forgot an `@` symbol. `npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-node` worked for me